# Error creating endpoint with aws Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to create any Endpoint from aws web page and I'm getting the following error:

```
The execution role ARN "Optional[com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::376362090250:assumed-role/MaeveControlPlane-release-DUB-Prod-Depl-LambdaRole-KR1KSTN4IDCP/PinImages-DUB-Prod is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::015415341044:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20200515T142190 (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: e5213159-dd7d-483a-a768-d1056f721d26; Proxy: null)]" is invalid. Please ensure that the role exists and that its trust relationship policy allows the action "sts:AssumeRole" for the service principal "sagemaker.amazonaws.com".
```

the strange thing is that I was able to create it yesterday, but I was changing some Roles and now it's impossible...

Please if anyone could help me...

Answer (score 0):

You probably changed the Trusted entities, I made that mistake now.

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "sagemaker.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```